# Problem with funcion scanf jump to the next scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem idk why jump from scanf name to scanf age, why dont let me put the address?
I already try only with %s instead of  %[^\n]s

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct contact
{
char name[40];
char address[80];
int age;
long phone;
};

typedef struct contact contact_L;

int main(void)
{
contact_L c1;

printf("Enter Name:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s",c1.name);

printf("Enter Address:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s",c1.address);

printf("Enter Age:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&c1.age);

printf("Enter Phone:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%ld",&c1.phone);

printf("Name: %s \n",c1.name);
printf("Address: %s \n",c1.address);
printf("Age: %d\n",c1.age);
printf("Phone: %ld\n",c1.phone);

return (0);

}
```

The output look like this  ( don't let me enter the address and jump to the age )

```
Enter Name:jose herrera
Enter Address:Enter Age:31
Enter Phone:4567890
//printf
Name: jose herrera 
Address:  
Age: 31
Phone: 4567890
```

Comment: `^\n` is quite useless as scanf stop with the first scanf char, plus you would need to restrict the size of the input. Prefer using `fgets`

Comment: `%[^\n]s` <= the `s` does not belong there. where did you learn to add `s`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
scanf(" %s",c1.address);
```

While Taking address input. With a preceding space